# Converting payload from Xilinx LwIP Ethernet back to float

Tags: c++, c, fpga, ethernet, xilinx

I am using LwIP to receive data on the Zynq7020 ARM CPU from my host via ethernet. I am sending floats via winsock. The issue is correctly decoding the p->payload in LwIP on the ARM cpu (zynq7020) back to a float again. I have tried various castings and conversion but nothing seems to work. When printing out the payload I get the same characters that I send from the host, so the 4 bytes of data is there.

I then cast the payload to a character array:

```
char * input = (char *)p->payload;
```

But then can't seem to correctly convert this character array to a float. I am not sure if the casting to the char * is correct in the first place and I can't find any information about the structure or format of the payload.

Any help is appreciated as I feel I have exhausted all my own ideas! 
Many thanks Sam

Comment: Two possible issues: Floating point format and word [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). My guess is the last.

Comment: Edianness shouldn't be an issue because the payload characters are in the same order as sent from the host. Its more the format conversion

Comment: That's the problem, if the *bytes* are in the same order it will be different values in a big-endianess (which ARM traditionally is) compared to little-endianess platforms (like x86).'

Comment: I get you know, i can use the winsock api to solve edianness. But i guess more of thr question is still how to correctly convert the payload to a float (omitting endianess for now)  thanks

Comment: Disregarding endianess issues (and possible compiler/platform differences in floating point format) then casting the other way around should work.